# Binding to a property of a list element of a model

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am having a model `Model1` with a property as `List<Model2> model2;`.

**Model1.cs**

```
//Other Properties
public List<Model2> model2List {get; set;}
```

And in `Model2` I have this property `Model3 model3;`

**Model2.cs**

```
// Other Properties
public Model3 model3 {get; set;}
```

**Model3.cs**

```
// Other Properties
public string Name {get; set;}
```

Now I have two User Controls `View1` and `View2` with `View2` defined in `View1`

**View1.xaml** UserControl

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <!-- Some properties here bind to those of model1 and model2 -->
    <views:View2 Name="view2"></views:View2>
</Grid>
```

**View2.xaml** UserControl

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
      <phone:LongListSelector
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=model3, Mode=OneWay}">
          <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel>
                      <Border
                          BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="3"
                          Margin="0,12">
                          <Grid>
                          <TextBlock Text={Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}>
                          </TextBlock>
                      </Border>
                      <views:View3 Name="view3">
                      </views:View3>
                  </StackPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
          </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
      </phone:LongListSelector>    
</Grid>
```

I am trying to bind TextBlock in View2.xaml to Property name in `Model3`. From my CS I have set DataContext as

`view2.DataContext = model1Object.model2List;`

Doesn't seem to be working. Also I need to bind controls in my `view3` defined in `view2` with properties of `model3`. I know this looks too confusing but I am stuck. Help!

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev Check if making sense now.

Comment: Put your complete xaml

Comment: @MatDev8 have added some more code.

Comment: So, first question => do you have something display in screen when you launch app? your list is loaded with items? model3 need to be a list.

Comment: @MatDev8 I figured out a way to solve first issue. I set DataContext of View2.xaml control from .cs to `model2List` and changed binding of my TextBox to {Binding model3.Name} and it works. However I am not able to bind items in `View3` to `Model3` properties which I posted as a different question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299290/binding-user-control-inside-longlistselector-with-current-item/26300309#26300309

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't properties.  Those are **fields**.   You cannot bind to fields.

Change your fields into properties by using automatic property definitions.

```
public Model3 Model3 {get;set;} // PascalCase for property names, thx
```

This may not be the only issue, but it's definitely incorrect to try and bind against fields.

Comment: It looks like these fields are private. Consider using public visibility too :)

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev oops!

Comment: Those are properties actually. I have edited the question. Help.