# Binding user control inside LongListSelector with current Item

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, binding

This is what I am doing.

**UserControl.xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
    <phone:LongListSelector
        Name="MainList"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                <views:PostView
                    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainList, Path=ItemsSource}">
                </views:PostView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataPanel>
```

I want controls inside my `PostView` to be bound with properties of Current ItemsSource element. But whats happening is, say I have List of 5 objects set as ItemsSource, every element in my `Post` view gets 5 values.

So I am getting 25 PostViews initialized, 5 per ItemsSource object, instead of 1.

Here is my `PostView.xaml` is it helps

**PostView.xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=User.Username, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
```

User is an Object property in the model I am binding to.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998578/how-to-bind-data-user-control-inside-listbox-wp8) to set up a dependency field for my data in `PostView.xaml.cs` and set it up from `UserControl.xaml`

Answer (score 2):

You are binding the user control to the whole collection, instead of just one item. Instead if `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainList, Path=ItemsSource}"` just use `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainList, Path=SelectedItem}"` or just `DataContext="{Binding}"` should work.

Comment: I tried with `{Binding}` earlier and just tried `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainList, Path=SelectedItem}"`. But its not working. With this, PostView is not even getting initialized.